# How to Change Column Data Types Dynamically in a Spark Dataframe based on Data Type

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm attempting to dynamically change data types in a dataframe based on the current data type (not the column name).  Currently, I'm using the following code to change all column data types dynamically to `StringType` in order to avoid data type conflict when dynamically loading data into Kudu:

```
val newdf = df.select(df.columns.map(c => col(c).cast(StringType)) : _*)
```

What I would like to do is change only certain column data type to a desired alternative data type (for example, all columns defined with `DateType` changed to `Timestamp`).

I've been searching for quite a while and have failed to find anything sufficient.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Greg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way of doing it:

```
df.printSchema
df.show()

root
 |-- Int_Col1: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- Dt_Col1: date (nullable = true)
 |-- Str_Col1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Dt_Col2: date (nullable = true)

+--------+----------+--------+----------+
|Int_Col1|   Dt_Col1|Str_Col1|   Dt_Col2|
+--------+----------+--------+----------+
|       1|1990-09-30|     AAA|1990-09-30|
|       2|2001-12-14|      BB|1990-09-30|
+--------+----------+--------+----------+
```

Then select only the `DateType` that we need to convert 
and change it to `TimestampType` using `foldLeft`.

```
val result = df.dtypes.collect{ case (dn, dt ) if dt.startsWith("DateType") => (dn,TimestampType)
                            case (dn, dt ) if dt.startsWith("IntegerType") => (dn,DoubleType)
                          }
           .foldLeft(df)((accDF, c) => accDF.withColumn(c._1, col(c._1).cast(c._2)))

result.printSchema
result.show(false)
```

Output:

```
root
 |-- Int_Col1: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- Dt_Col1: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- Str_Col1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Dt_Col2: timestamp (nullable = true)

+--------+-------------------+--------+-------------------+
|Int_Col1|Dt_Col1            |Str_Col1|Dt_Col2            |
+--------+-------------------+--------+-------------------+
|1       |1990-09-30 00:00:00|AAA     |1990-09-30 00:00:00|
|2       |2001-12-14 00:00:00|BB      |1990-09-30 00:00:00|
+--------+-------------------+--------+-------------------+
```

Comment: That works great!  Thanks so much!  If I wanted to change more than one data type, could I just add another case statement under the first one?

Comment: I did, however I don't have enough reputation yet for it to show up... apologies... it was a huge help!

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, then please let me know how to accept

Comment: christ.... I was clicking the up arrow... can you tell it's my first question?  :)